# Best practice to change the text direction for Asian users?

Tags: ios, text, language

I'm working on an iOS 8 note taking app that will be released in the US but also in Asian countries. For the latter I need to change the text direction from the default "left to right" to "right to left".
Should I let the user change the settings through a toggle or what is the best practice for such a case?

Comment: "Asian" is not a country or language. Either specify which language you are referring to or remove it. Chinese, Japanese, Korean are all LTR languages.

Answer (score 3):

A toggle might take too much space, and will be unnecessary for people who only uses one language.

Should you have a language selector screen instead? And change the text direction base on what language was chosen?

Another way I can think of is to change it base on user's current keyboard, but I'm not sure if that's technically doable.

Comment: +1 for "...change the text direction based on what language was chosen." Surely you don't need to have an explicit toggle for direction in its own right.